# Triangle - length of the sides - proof

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, inequality, proof-writing

a, b and c are the lengths of the sides of a triangle. Prove that 
$$a^2+b^2 \ge \frac{1}{2}c^2$$ 
 
Let $\gamma$ be the angle between sides a and b. then: 
$$a^2 + b^2 - 2ab\cos(\gamma) = c^2$$ 
Hence we need to prove that 
$$a^2+b^2 \ge \frac{1}{2}c^2$$ 
$$2a^2+2b^2 \ge a^2+b^2 -2ab\cos(\gamma) $$
$$a^2+b^2+2ab\cos(\gamma) \ge0$$ 
Knowing that $\cos(\gamma) \ge-1$, we get $a^2+b^2+2ab\cos(\gamma) \ge a^2 +b^2 -2ab =(a-b)^2$ 
I have carried this problem so far but now I am stuck. How should I proceed?

Comment: what will you do further? your proof is complete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're already there. Your last line is

$$a^2+b^2+2ab\cos(\gamma) \geq (a-b)^2$$

And so you only have to note $(a-b)^2\geq 0$ to see that

$$a^2+b^2+2ab\cos(\gamma) \geq 0$$

Note that we can make this inequality strict ($>$) since $\cos(\gamma)=-1$ can't happen, for one angle is then stretched, so we could've taken $\cos(\gamma)>-1$ rather than $\cos(\gamma)\ge-1$.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

Triangle inequality theorem: a + b > c .

The sum of the lengths of two sides of a triangle is greater than the length of the third side.

1) $(a + b)^2 > c^2$ ; or

2)$ a^2 + 2ab + b^2 > c^2$.

Now:

3)$ (a -b)^2 \ge 0$;  hence : $a^2 + b^2 \ge 2ab$.

Putting together:

$ 2a^2 + 2b^2 \ge a^2 + 2ab + b^2 \gt c^2 .$

Answer (score 0):

The squared [length of the median](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/triangle/LengthOfMedian.shtml) through $C$ is exactly $\frac{1}{4}\left(2a^2+2b^2-c^2\right)$ and that gives $a^2+b^2\geq \frac{1}{2}c^2$ as a straightforward consequence.